# Can I open Google Glass native app using GCM

Tags: android, google-glass

I have an idea to open the Google Glass native application using GCM service.

Could anybody help me with this. Is that possible.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there is no Google Play Services on Glass. Thus you can't register for GCM messages on Glass.

However, I do see `GCMBroadcastReceiver` in GlassHome's apk manifest, so I assume, they added (or in progress of adding) some pieces of Play Services. Will see what's gonna happen when they officially release Glass :)

Just to summarize, no, it is not possible to open native Glass app using GCM. At least right now

Comment: Yes I understand the situation but this GlassBridge software dose that. See this http://www.geek.com/review/glassbridge-turns-android-apps-into-glass-apps-1562163/

Comment: Why do you think it uses GCM? As far as I can see - it uses the same Mirror API to communicate with Glass

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thin using the Mirror API to insert a card that can then be used to launch a GDK app.  Specifying a menu item as like below will insert a card with a menu that the user can tap to launch

```
"menuItems":[
      {
         "action":"OPEN_URI",
         "id":"OpenAppId",
         "payload":"my.package.name.scheme://open?param1=value1&param2=value2",
         "values":[
           {
             "displayName":"Accept",
             "iconUrl":"https://my_url_dot_com/glass_menu_icons/ic_done_50.png",
             "state":"DEFAULT"
           },
           {
             "displayName":"Accepting",
             "state":"PENDING"
           },
           {
             "displayName":"Accepted",
             "state":"CONFIRMED"
           }
         ]
      },
```

You'll need this intent filter on your Android manifest file:

```
 <intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="my.package.name.scheme" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

And can then access the query params passed in the payload as Intent extras.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.Ihave solved that problem using same way you mentioned .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965155/opening-gdk-glassware-through-mirror-api-glassware-menuitem/20977865#20977865