# Opening GDK Glassware through Mirror API Glassware MenuItem

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I have problem integrating GDK Glassware and Mirror API Glassware as described [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/index). I need to open GDK glassware application using Mirroe api Glassware app MenuItem. Can I send data bundle with intent. Does anybody have an idea about that.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I start an intent from a card in Google Glass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790374/how-can-i-start-an-intent-from-a-card-in-google-glass)

Comment: Can I send data using this method?. This is not answering to my problem. But thank you very much.

Comment: Nice question, is it possible to pass data from timeline card to native app, like we do in normal android using bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally figured out a way to do that

1. First add your custom scheme to android activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
    
     <activity
           android:name="com.sanath.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
             <data android:scheme="com.sanath.scheme" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>
           <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
           android:resource="@xml/vision_voice_trigger" />
       </activity>
   ```
2. Then in Glassware timeline MenuItem add like following

   ```
   new MenuItem(){
   Action = "OPEN_URI",
   Payload = "com.sanath.scheme://open/Welcome/2014",
   Values = new MenuValue[]
           {
            new MenuValue()
            {
               DisplayName  = "Open",
               State = "DEFAULT"
            },
            new MenuValue()
            {
               DisplayName  = "Launching",
               State = "PENDING"
            },
            new MenuValue()
            {
                DisplayName  = "Launched",
                State = "CONFIRMED"
            },
            },
           },
       }
   ```
3. Then inside your Activity OnCreate method you can get data as following

   ```
      Uri data = getIntent().getData();
           List params = data.getPathSegments();
           String param0 = params.get(0); // "welcome"
           String param1 = params.get(1); //"2014"
   ```

   String welcomeMsg = param0+" to "+param1;

       /*show time line card
        * */
       Card welcomeCard =new Card(this);
       welcomeCard.setText(welcomeMsg);
       welcomeCard.setFootnote(param1);
       View view =welcomeCard.toView();

       setContentView(view);

Hope this will help others

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to provide data through bundle, but you can use query parameters or hash fragment in your `URI` to provide the necessary data.

Example:

```
myscheme://<SOME_PATH>?param1=value1&param2&value2
```

Then, in your GDK Glassware, simply parse the query parameters and process their values.

Comment: Thank you Alain.Realy appreciate your help and I will try this method.