# Mirror API Multiple OPEN_URI Intents not appearing on menu

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

The mirror api's menu items are only displaying 1 of two open URI intents.

Is there a way to get the behavior so that a user can own have two different URI_OPEN payloads on the same card?

I have it properly configured from this referenced question, but it only shows the first available OPEN_URI. 
[Menu Item for "OPEN_URI" not present in menuItems return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105005/menu-item-for-open-uri-not-present-in-menuitems-return)

If 'fooApp' shows up first, it is the only one available but if 'barApp' appears first it is shown.

Returns
(Foo App, Reply, Delete)
OR
(Bar App, Reply, Delete)

but not Foo App, Bar App, Reply, Delete (desired)

```
        "menuItems": [
              {
                "action": "OPEN_URI",
                "id": "1",
                "payload": "fooApp://",
                "values": [{
                  "displayName": "Foo App",
                  "iconUrl":"http://www.image.com/x.png"
                }]
              },
              {
                "action": "OPEN_URI",
                "id": "2",
                "payload": "barApp://",
                "values": [{
                  "displayName": "Bar App",
                  "iconUrl":"http://www.image.com/x.png"
                }]
              },
            {"action": "REPLY"},
            {"action": "DELETE"},
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your menu items seem to have the same id.  Try using a different id value for each one.

Comment: Ah I had tried that before, but rolled back. Still no change ;|

Comment: One more thing to try would be in the values array add the "state" : "DEFAULT" property.  Sometimes I've seen menu items fail to show when the state property isn't provided.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but enduring that the menu value had at least a DEFAULT state worked for me. This was mentioned by John Fontaine in his comments.